# NodeJS Calling a function when a txt. file is updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am trying to achieve the following in NodeJS:

Monitor a `.txt` file so when there are any changes applied to it a callback function will be triggered.

Now I know how to how to read from a text file with a stream. For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = '';

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('my-file.txt', 'utf8');

readStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But this code just reads the `.txt` file once. Is it possible to keep monitoring it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use - [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener)

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.watch('text.txt', function(eventType, filename) {
    console.log('File was updated');
});
```

Comment: To add here `fs.watch` API has some caveats and inconsistency that comes with it like two events trigger using `fs.writeFile` one for open and one for write. Read more: [link](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) & [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2126)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use chokidar npm module for the monitoring purpose.**

[Chokidar npm module link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar)

```
// Initialize watcher.
const watcher = chokidar.watch('my-file.txt', {
  ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../,
  persistent: true
});

// Something to use when events are received.
const log = console.log.bind(console);

// Add event listeners.
 watcher
  .on('add', path => log(`File ${path} has been added`))
  .on('change', path => log(`File ${path} has been changed`))
  .on('unlink', path => log(`File ${path} has been removed`))
  .on('addDir', path => log(`Directory ${path} has been added`))
  .on('unlinkDir', path => log(`Directory ${path} has been removed`))
  .on('error', error => log(`Watcher error: ${error}`))
  .on('ready', () => log('Initial scan complete. Ready for changes'))
  .on('raw', (event, path, details) => { // internal
    log('Raw event info:', event, path, details);
  });
```